# How to set outline without using CSS outline property?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set outline of mouseovered element with Javascript and CSS.

In chrome, CSS outline property works well but not in Internet Explorer(I use IE9).

I tested CSS border property but it decrease width of actual content.

My purpose is setting outline without CSS outline property and content's area isn't changed.

The solution should support IE 7~9 and if also IE6 it's the best.

Comment: if you use javascript why can't you just use border and using javascript width by proper amount? (most likely 2 pixels - 1 for each side).

Comment: You could also use `border: 1px solid transparent;` for the non-bordered version. Should work almost anywhere.

Comment: if I set transparent border, total width of element(border + content's width) increases. i must not change total width of element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tested CSS border property but it decrease width of actual content.*

Yes, you'd have to adjust the rest of your layout to account for the border of x pixels that you introduce - it will take up space from somewhere, it's up to you to set appropriate dimensions, margins and padding to compensate.

Comment: I must not change anything in layout and have to make outline like CSS outline property does. If I set border and decrease content's width. total width of element is same. but change of content's width may make diffrence in page view(i.e linebreak of text)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the element in a `<div>` with a transparent border. Color the border on mouseover.

You can add the transparent border to the element itself (and color on mouseover) if you don't mind the content width reducing by a constant amount i.e. the content width won't change on mouseover.

Comment: If I wrap element width <div> element, it requires additional area for border of <div> element. I must not change anything in layout. I have to make outline like CSS outline property does.